# Mobile Menu not working on other navbar pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a problem regarding my Website mobile menu. Currently on the index page it works perfectly fine, but when switching to another page, it shows the side menu. For some reason this is because I am removing a banner and it seems to make the navbar's width smaller. Below will be my html and CSS code. If I keep the header tag in the other pages html code it works fine, but I do not want the header on the other pages as it does not look very appealing.

Here's the code:

```js
var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks")
    function showMenu(){
        navLinks.style.right = "0";
    }
    function hideMenu(){
        navLinks.style.right = "-250px";
    }
```

```css
.header{
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('images/background-image.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar{
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 5%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
}


.logo a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.nav-links{
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
}

.nav-links .fas{
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.nav-links ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.nav-links ul li a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-links ul li:after{
    content: '';
    width: 0%;
    height: 3px;
    background: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav-links ul li:hover:after{
    width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
    html, body{
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .text-box h1{
        font-size: 35px;
    }
    .nav-links ul li{
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .nav-links{
        position: absolute;
        background: black;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 250px;
        top: 0;
        right: -250px;
        text-align: left;
        z-index: 2;
        transition: 1s;
    }

    .navbar ul li{
        margin-left: 45px;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }

    .navbar .fas{
        display: inline-block;
        color: #fff;
        margin: 10px;
        font-size: 22px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .navbar ul li:hover{
        text-decoration: underline 3px #fff;
    } 

    .nav-links ul li:hover:after{
    width: 0;
    }

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<section class="header">
        <nav class="navbar">
            <h1 class="logo"><a href="#">SHOE REPAIR</a></h1>
            <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
                <i class="fas fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html"><i class="fas fa-concierge-bell"></i>SERVICES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about-us.html"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact-us.html"><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <i class="fas fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
        </nav>
    </section>
```

First picture is how it should look which works fine on the Home page, second picture is what it does on all other pages.

[image: How the Menu should look when pulled out]

[image: How the Menu looks on the other tabs (service, about, contact)]

Comment: Did you already use the `<meta scale` on that page?

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 Pretty positive, I have this on each page: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">